# Cordova android app is slow in wifi

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I am using Cordova 6.2.0 for my android project. Also using simple ajax library which found from git : https://github.com/ded/reqwest. My app is very slow when i am using wifi.

Comment: Why are you using additional library for AJAX

Comment: i am not using jquery or any other libraries..

Comment: Then use jquery instead of any other library

Comment: is there any issue with reqwest?

Comment: How can I say if don't post any code. But why should use additional library when there is javascript framework like jquery.